# How do you catch exceptions during class loading

Tags: python, sqlite, exception, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLite database and use SQLAlchemy to map the tables to classes. The generate layout is that I have a parent table and a child table. A Parent class may have multiple children, and a Child only one parent. The children are loaded into a custom collection class for various pre and post processing.

There are times that an exception may be raised during the loading of the Child class. This is somewhat abnormal operation, usually due to database corruption or an exceedingly old database, but it does require intervention. However I don't seem to have any way of catching this exception.

As a work around, I assume that instead of raising an Exception, I could flag the class with a `self.delete = True` and check for this when loading into the collection class. But it still begs the question about what to do about exceptions that may raise during loading of a class from the database mapper?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that the Exceptions are happening in my `@reconstructor` metho, which SQLAlchemy calls after loading the object

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple way to treat this would be to wrap access to the children in a proper `try-except` clause. To avoid having `try-except` clauses all over the place you could e.g. wrap the relation in a standard python property:

```
class Parent:

    # your current standard children relationship
    _children = relationship('Child')

    @property
    def children(self):
        # try accessing and possibly loading the children
        try:
            return self._children

        # catch and handle the possibly occuring exception
        except WhatEverException:
            handleException()
```

Obviously this will not handle cases where loading a `Child` instance is triggered from someplace else, but it might be start.

Naturally, the better choice would be to try and avoid the exceptions.
But this of course pretty much depends on what kind of exceptions you're actually talking about.

Comment: Wouldn't this only catch exceptions that are caught when accessing the children attribute in Parent? I'm talking when the relationship is loaded from SQLAlachemy when it loads the parent object. sqlalchemy calls the @reconstructer, and this is where the exception happens (I probably should add that to the OP)

Comment: You claimed exceptions occur `during the loading of the Child class`. Accessing the children property would usually be one of the key places that triggers loading of `Child` instances. You'd have to be more specific about when / where / what Exception exactly it is that occurs...

Comment: With your example, it would be equivalent to the exception happening when SQLAlchemy tries to store `_children` from the relationship, not when the program tried to access the children.

Comment: Also, we are not using a declarative base. the program uses the more classical mapper() to map Classes with Tables

Comment: Well okay - that's lots of stuff differing from what I assumed. What makes you think my property example would catch exceptions when storing children? I've only implemented a getter - and even in `parent.children += some_child` the `_children` attribute itself is only accessed in reading fashion.

Comment: I don't think it would work because of the use case that I have. When the exception is raised, the class doesn't even make it to my custom collection class (which would be the list that is formed for `_children`). The way I understand it is that SQLAlchemy loads the class and calls the @reconstructer, then adds it to the collections class. I can verify this by looking at the stack - the only file of mine is the one that raises the exception. The fact that it fails when it loads before it even touches my codebase is what is throwing me off.

Comment: So, if accessing `_children` is what triggers (!) SQLAlchemy to load the related objects than my example will catch the exception. It doesn't matter whether the exceptions happens before the objects are actually attached to the collection.